# vcenter server failed point to new server

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

The machine that was running my vcenter server/database for my esxi host failed and is unrecoverable.

My ESXI host v5.0.0 is still pointed at that old server and I am only able to login with the vSphere Client directly to the server using the root credentials. When I log in it says

```
"this host is currently being managed by the vCenter Server with IP address:      192.168.1.10"
```

Although the server 192.168.1.10 no longer exists . I've created a new vcenter server but how do i recreate the database and point the esxi host to the new vcenter instance?

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices here.

**Recover**

Assuming you had backups of the database, you can fully install vCenter, with a new database and once it's all up and running, you simply restore the original database over top of it, restart your services and you're off to the races.

**Rebuild**

You can simply install vCenter from scratch and add the hosts to this new vCenter. It will pick up all you VMs and datastores, but not much else. You'll have to recreate/configure your Clusters, Datacenters, Storage Clusters, Distributed Switches and most other things.

That said, this might be a good time to call VMware and get some support...